# Intel SGX root key

Tags: security, cryptography, intel, digital-signature, sgx

I am building an app that uses Intel SGX to sign a certain type of activities the app performs. Within a Secure Enclave I generate a statement X of the kind "operation A was performed with result B". Next, I generate a one-time key Y to sign this statement. The key X itself is a part of an SGX quote, i.e., is signed with the chain of keys (K1, K2, ...) provided by SGX technology. This chain terminates at the so called Intel SGX Root Key (R).

```
R -> K1 -> K2 -> ... -> Y -> X ("operation = A ; result = B")
```

I want to store statement X somewhere else such that 1 year later anyone would be able to verfiy that indeed an operation A was performed with result B. In this case, the verifier would unwind the chain of trust starting from the Intel SGX Root Key (R) until they reach my one-time key Y, and finally verify the statement X.

The question is, where do I get the key R from?

When we deal with this type of cryptographic schemes, the ultimate key to trust is somewhere in the public, e.g., on one of the main pages of Intel's website. However, it is kind of challenging to find it. Any idea where one could obtain it from?